# How find the cause of node error with messages containing pg_protocol

Tags: node.js

I have a quasar app with backend node. My node randomly shows this error message during execution.

I've looked in several places, but I don't know where the error comes from.

I use PostgresSQL, socketIO , sequelize and typeorm. But I have logged all database operations and I see no error.

Could anyone give me a tip on where to look?

```
[ERROR] 13:20:23 RangeError: The value of "offset" is out of range. It must be >= 0 and <= 90876. Received 1948435524 
Sun, 08 Oct 2023 16:20:23 GMT uncaughtException: The value of "offset" is out of range. It must be >= 0 and <= 90876. Received 1948435524 
RangeError: The value of "offset" is out of range. It must be >= 0 and <= 90876. Received 1948435524 
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5) 
    at boundsError (node:internal/buffer:86:9) 
    at Buffer.readInt32BE (node:internal/buffer:482:5) 
    at BufferReader.int32 (F:\Programas\vuejs\izing.open.io\backbaileys\node_modules\pg-protocol\src\buffer-reader.ts:29:32) 
    at Parser.parseDataRowMessage (F:\Programas\vuejs\izing.open.io\backbaileys\node_modules\pg-protocol\src\parser.ts:286:31) 
    at Parser.handlePacket (F:\Programas\vuejs\izing.open.io\backbaileys\node_modules\pg-protocol\src\parser.ts:174:21) 
    at Parser.parse (F:\Programas\vuejs\izing.open.io\backbaileys\node_modules\pg-protocol\src\parser.ts:103:30) 
    at Socket.<anonymous> (F:\Programas\vuejs\izing.open.io\backbaileys\node_modules\pg-protocol\src\index.ts:7:48) 
    at Socket.emit (node:events:394:28) 
    at Socket.emit (node:domain:475:12) 
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12) 
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9) 
    at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10) 
    at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:199:23)
```